# Iterate through API and extract fields in Power Query in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I’m trying to get all work items related to a Visual Studio Team Services board.

I’m surprised there is no “Get all work items” query in the API that Microsoft has published here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items

So therefore I made a custom query in VSTS where I get all work items from current sprint.

The problem is that Power BI shows the result as following:

[image]

This is sadly not good enough as I have to Navigate into List => Convert to Table => Expand columns and find out that the only thing it shows is ID and URL as this:

[image]

I need to get into the URL and grab hold of the fields in each and every URL like this:

[image]

But this doesn’t seem to be that simple. 
It is not adequate for me to specify the ID for each element like in the example as this is not scalable: 
https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=297,299,300&api-version=1.0

I need to iterate on the id of all the elements, combine/concatenate it with the URL at the end in the query so I can access the underlying fields.

I have tried to do this with partial success:

[image]

If I click on “Record” it gives me the fields within the specified work item through its ID. This is all good, but I am not able to increment the number. Only the first row is successful, and all other are left as “null”.

I have tried to write some Power Query and looked at the example given from DataChant:
Iterate over dynamic Web API Pages with Power Query - How to resolve Cursor-Based Pagination - DataChant

This is almost the exact same thing as I am trying to do, but I am not experienced in Power Query.

How would I go by fixing this?

This is my code:

```
    let    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://dxno.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/DX/_apis/wit/wiql/222fd0c3-5ae6-4fad-86e8-23b0fa5fc6e7?api-version=2.2")),
    workItems = Source[workItems],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(workItems, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "url"}, {"Column1.id", "Column1.url"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Column1",{"Column1.url"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column1.id", "itemNumber"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"itemNumber", Int64.Type}}),
    itemNumber = #"Changed Type"[itemNumber],

    min = List.Min(itemNumber),
    max = List.Max(itemNumber),
    Variance = max-min,
    CountOfLoops = Number.ToText(Variance),


    iterations = Variance,
    url = Text.Combine({"https://dxno.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/", CountOfLoops}, ""), 

FnGetOnePage =
  (url) as record =>
   let
    Sourcie = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url)),
    fields = try Sourcie[fields] otherwise null,
    res = [Data=fields]
   in
    res,

 GeneratedList =
  List.Generate(()=>[i=0, res = FnGetOnePage(url)], 
   each [i]null,
   each [i=[i]+1, res = FnGetOnePage([res])],
   each [res][Data])
in

    GeneratedList
```

Comment: Formatting tip: You can insert line breaks in your PowerQuery code as well as use additional let statements to improve readability. (And even if you couldn't, we would appreciate extra line breaks here on SO.)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, it's now been edited.